# R - c() unexpectedly converts names of named vectors into UTF-8. Is this a bug?

Tags: r, character-encoding

I've faced a strange behavior of `c()` with R 3.3.2 on Windows with non-US-English locale. It converts the names of named vectors into UTF-8.

```
x <- "φ"
names(x) <- "φ"

Encoding(names(x))
#> [1] "unknown"

Encoding(names(c(x)))
#> [1] "UTF-8"
```

Thought this issue is not problematic for most people, it is critical for those who uses named vectors as lookup tables (example is here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#applications). I am also the one who stuck with [the behavior of dplyr's select() function](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/2284).

I'm not quite sure whether this behavior is a bug or by design. Should I submit a bug report to R core?

Here's info about my R environment:

```
sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=Japanese_Japan.932  LC_CTYPE=Japanese_Japan.932    LC_MONETARY=Japanese_Japan.932
#> [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Japanese_Japan.932    
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#> [1] tools_3.3.2
```

Comment: I am also using 3.3.2, the output of the two Encoding calls are the same 'UTF-8' on my PC.

Comment: @mt1022 Thanks for confirmation. I guess this problem occurs only on Windows. Are you using Windows PC?

Comment: No. I am using a mac.

Comment: I also get UTF-8 on both Encoding calls. I'm using 3.3.2 on Windows, but with the default US-English locale.

Comment: @mt1022 Thanks. Then, you won't see this problem :)

Comment: @HongOoi Thanks for information! I've confirmed that both return UTF-8 after `Sys.setlocale(locale = "C")`. This problem seems to occur only when the locale is not US-English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should still see `names(c(x)) == names(x)` on your system. The encoding change by `c()` may be unintentional, but shouldn't affect your code in most scenarios.

On Windows, which doesn't have a UTF-8 locale, your safest bet is to convert *all* strings to UTF-8 first via `enc2utf8()`, and then stay in UTF-8. This will also enable safe lookups.

[Language symbols](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.3.2/topics/name) (as used in dplyr's `group_by()`) are an entirely different issue. For some reason they are always interpreted in the native encoding. (Try `as.name(names(c(x)))`.) However, it's still best to have them in UTF-8, and convert to native just before calling `as.name()`. This is what dplyr should be doing, we're just not quite there yet.

My recommendation is to use ASCII-only characters for column names when using dplyr on Windows. This requires some discipline if you're relying on `tidyr::spread()` for non-ASCII column contents. You could also consider switching to a system (OS X or Linux) that works with UTF-8 natively.

Comment: Thanks! I know I won't face any problem in most cases since R respects UTF-8 as described [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Encoding.html). The only case I know is dplyr's `group_by()` and `distinct()`. Anyway, your suggestion seems right and very reasonable to me. Thanks.